# Custom html tags -- Is there a better way?

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to complete a browser plugin that will analyze text and mark it in some fashion.

Basically, 
let's say your browsing and you see this come across this text somewhere in your page.

```
<p>and then Tom Cruise, devoured the planet.</p>
```

The plugin is scanning the text and will find "Tom Cruise." Once moused over spit AJAX at my server and return a HTML page to be will be displayed in a tool tip.

I originally marked it like so

```
<p>and then <span class="ajax subtleShadow">Tom Cruise</span>, devoured the planet.</p>
```

Though i am discovering that this can go wrong, if the webpage has strange span css or if its nested in a span with strange things like borders.

My solution was to INVENT a new html tags. like so...

```
<p>and then <fhwdgads class="ajax subtleShadow">Tom Cruise</fhwdgads>, devoured the planet.</p>
```

Though a quick search lead me to the conclusion that "the internet" would come after me with pitchforks should I do so.

Is there another way to mark inline text creation of custom tags?

EDIT : [Link to a view of the broken button in the nested spans.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMxsM.jpg)

Comment: You have forgotten to add you markup. As for you "inventing" new HTML tags - no. You are using custom elements, but they won't magically become part of the HTML standard.

Comment: Yea first post.... I blundered

Comment: I didn't know borders were strange things.

Comment: everyday people trying to have less markup and you want some more markups? :D

Comment: In what way does it go wrong in the presence of borders, or other 'strange CSS'? And if you want to create new elements I believe you're [allowed to create your own doctype](http://m.alistapart.com/articles/customdtd/).

Comment: like this [Messed up Buttons](http://i.imgur.com/RasEH.jpg)

Comment: I haven't got time for a full response, but when creating a third-party widget you should always put the web site's content first and your widget should not break it. Using classes such as `.ajax` and `.subtleShadow` should conflict with the site's own CSS, so make these unique to your widget, eg. `.widget-name-ajax`. Moreover, when you've found a string you wish to use, check to see if it's already wrapped in a span - if so, simply add your unique class to that. Also, I would suggest you leave strings found in `a` tags alone - this could become very confusing for the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s really no guarantee that `<fhwdgads>` is never recognized as a tag with some special semantics or formatting. It might be improbable if you use a very messy tag name, but would you, really? People tend to use mnemonic names when they invent tags, and then there’s a real chance of clashing with tags in some current or future spec or browser.

Moreover, some old versions of IE ignore unrecognized tags completely, e.g. do not let you style them. This can be avoided using `document.createElement()` once for each tag name, though.

Using `span` or `div` is as such safe in practice. There is no reason to think that browsers have some fancy formatting for them by default. Just as we don’t stop using `h1` even though it is theoretically possible that it will make the content pink and blinking. It’s impossible to be foolproof if you expect browser vendors to be totally crazy.

Using classes is a different matter, though only in the sense that other style sheets play with the same class names as you. You might need to work in an environment where other author style sheets interfere with yours. But this just calls for caution; it does not make a `span` or `div` element with a class the wrong tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<DIV>` tag instead. Based from my "experience", the div element pretty much goes anywhere on the html hierarchy (inside `<body>` and not inside input tags). You must note the default styles though.

Comment: And not inside  in-line elements. But why would using a `div` solve the problem?

Comment: Inserting a `div` element would almost certainly destroy the site's design. Third party widgets should sit alongside site content - not ruin it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the using of custom html tags is not a bad way. Of course I can't promise that you have not any related technical problems with developing of your plugin. But Facebook did: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/

I don't know why it has been removed.

You can also add your special namespace extention (like fb: for Facebook). Web 2.0 supports independence of data representation and user-defined tags: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_2.0#Concepts

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to define a CSS-class that first resets *all* style properties so you can start off with a clean slate.

Another solution would be to use tags that are not used very often such as `del`, `ins` and `blockquote`