# Make new HTML tag which acts like an exist tag with extras

Tags: html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Custom html tags — Is there a better way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13230005/custom-html-tags-is-there-a-better-way)

I using finding myself very frequently writing: `<pre class="cpp">`, when using highlight.js. Just out of interest, is there any way I could make a new tag, say `<pcpp>`, which would act exactly like `<pre class="cpp">`, just using CSS?

I can imagine this would be possible with JavaScript, but I would not want to start changing all my tags every time the page is loaded.

Comment: I strongly advise against doing this. There is no good reason for it.

Comment: Your problem then would be more likely at highlight.js as it selects just `<pre>` tags.

Comment: Validators will return errors if you use custom tags outside HTMl standard, which is not good in many case, especially with search engines.

Comment: There are several old questions about the same topic, usually using the phrase “custom tags”.

Comment: If this is just about saving keystrokes, maybe it's time to start looking at autocompletion plugins for your editor.  For instance, Notepad++ has a plugin called FingerText where you type in the keyword then hit tab and it fills in your configured text/markup.

Comment: Unless you want to write your own DOCTYPE, no.

Answer (score -1):

No, but if you are using JavaScript anyways then you can apply the `cpp` class to all `<pre>` elements if you're finding that you're applying that class to every `<pre>` element on the page:

```
// Using jQuery
$('pre').addClass('cpp');
```

Making a new element would probably cause major issues with the page, much more trouble than it's worth, and it wouldn't validate as HTML anymore.

Comment: Why do that at all?  Why not just give the `pre` tag the styling that the `cpp` class provides?

Comment: @cimmanon Because the `cpp` class is also acted on by another JavaScript file, as the OP has stated.

Comment: Yes, I am using a library which wants me to use <pre class="cpp">. I think I will just this javascript.

Comment: @ChrisJefferson Be sure that the class is added (via this JavaScript) before the other library initializes. If this answer resolves your issue please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score -1):

No you are not supposed to create new tag in HTML